# Saving Stats with Java IO

Tags: java, 3d

I have a file and a basic reader and writer set up but when I change the value it doesn't write the new value 
Here's the code:

int constitutionLevel, strengthLevel;

```
int[] saveStats = { constitutionLevel, strengthLevel };

int constitutionLevelLocation = 0;
int strengthLevelLocation = 1;

public StatSaver()
{
    constitutionLevel = Constitution.getConstitutionLevel();
    strengthLevel = Strength.getStrengthLevel();
}

public void startSaving()
{
    readPlayer("SaveManagement/Stats/save.txt");
    updatePlayerStats();
    savePlayer("SaveManagement/Stats/save.txt");
}

private void updatePlayerStats()
{
    System.out.println("Saving Stats...");
    System.out.println(constitutionLevel);
    constitutionLevel = saveStats[constitutionLevelLocation];
    strengthLevel = saveStats[strengthLevelLocation];
    System.out.println(constitutionLevel);
    System.out.println("Done Saving Stats");
}

private void readPlayer(String filePath)
{
    File inputFile;
    BufferedReader inputReader;

    try
    {
        inputFile = new File(filePath);
        inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

        for (int i = 0; i < saveStats.length; i++)
        {
            saveStats[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputReader.readLine());
        }

        inputReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

}

private void savePlayer(String filePath)
{
    File outputFile;
    BufferedWriter outputWriter;

    try
    {
        outputFile = new File(filePath);
        outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
        outputWriter.write(saveStats[0] + "\n");
        outputWriter.write(saveStats[1] + "\n");
        //for (int i = 0; i < saveStats.length; i++)
        //{
        //  outputWriter.write(saveStats[i] + "\n");
        //}

        outputWriter.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

}
```

As you can see I have a line of code commented out but the two lines of code right above do the same thing I just have to type a few more things, I could change it for something bigger but since I have two stats right now I am not in any rush.  The only solution that is short term would be to change the value in the .txt file but that would not work when I public the game because everybody would put the stat at infinity.  Anyways please help and Thanks in advance!

Comment: `startSaving` isn't called from this code. Are you sure it is getting called?

Comment: I call it when I stop and cleanup the game.

Answer (score 0):

So, in your startSaving() method, you read in information from readPlayer() (which I assume is the old values stored in the file), and then place the values into the array. In the updatePlayerStats(), you take the values in the array, and put them into the two variables (overwriting what was placed in them by the constructor). Lastly, the savePlayer() method takes the information from the array, and saves them into the file. At no point did you change the values in the array, so no new numbers are being added to the file.